# Protect from 3D Printer fumes

Tags: safety, health-and-safety, air-quality, air-filter, child-safety

I'm planning to buy 3D Printer that can only print with ABS (Zortrax). I have a small child (3 months old) at my flat so I'm afraid that fumes can have negative impact on her health.

- What should I buy or make to absorb fumes produced by 3d Printer?
- Are there any solutions tailored specially for 3d Printing ?
- What kind of filters should be used ?

Comment: Not really a home improvement question. (Insert rant here about misleading DIY.)

Comment: Seems to me that if you don't want to breath it, neither would the people outside the window. If the fumes are toxic, or hazardous in any way, you'll want to exhaust them in an approved manner. If you're going to blow it outside untreated, I'd at least exhaust out the roof.  That should at least keep it away from other people.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a hobby project rather than home improvement.

Comment: I'm having the same concern. Can you upload a photo of your solution if you have already produced it? My email: leandromcarvalho@yahoo.com.br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a box (perhaps a prefab cabinet) around the printer, and a duct leading to an exhaust fan connected to the box, leading to outside (through a wall, or if renting, through a fan-plate inserted in a window opening.)

I would NOT depend on any sort of filter.

Comment: Thanks! I started preparing project based on your opinion ignoring filters - just extracting air out of my house by window ventilation. Perhaps I will add some HEPA or Carbon filter into the mix later.

Answer (score 3):

Having done 3D printing with ABS myself, I'm familiar with this challenge. You need to exhaust the fumes--that's the long and short of it. Locate the printer near a window, open the window, and have a fan blowing air out the window every time you use the printer. Crack a window on the other side of your house for make-up air purposes.

Or print with PLA, which does not generate nasty fumes. PLA is a nice material and smells a little like popcorn when melted.

Comment: Unfortunately PLA is not an option for me. Thank you for your answer but my concern is health of my child - this is why I want to do something more then you described.

Comment: It's also fun when the fan blows bits of dust and other materials into the material as it sets up.  ;-)

Comment: Air movement is an inherently imperfect solution, since it will affect the cooling characteristics of the material. No way around that, really.

Answer (score 3):

Look into a downdraft table that you can exhaust outside. These are typically used for sanding or painting but the premise is the same. The table is perforated and sucks air down and then out to a dust collector or other exaust mechanism.  You would place the printer on the table and ensure the exaust is running while you print.